# Difficulty using CAST/CONVERT with SQLCMD in order to assign stored procedure variables

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, sqlcmd

I am attempting to make a stored procedure work by triggering the SP through a batch file using SQLCMD, with user-defined variables.  I can already confirm my stored procedure works, because I tested it this way using hard-coded variables.
For reference, this is the batch file code:

```
SET /P Param1 = Enter job number here:
SET /P Param2 = Enter number for current status here:

sqlcmd -S DevTest -d test_database -Q "EXEC dbo.JStatUpd @jobNum = Param1, @stat = Param2"

PAUSE
```

*(EDIT: I have left the sqlcmd line as-is for ease of reference.)*

My difficulty lies in working with user-defined variables.  Specifically, I'm having an issue converting the user-defined variables--both of my variables should be integers.
I recognize that all of the `SET` variables automatically come in as `nvarchar`, but I haven't been able to find a way to convert them to `int`; I've gotten errors for each attempt I've made at using CAST or CONVERT.

My question is:  Is it possible to to convert variables using CAST or CONVERT inside the SQLCMD in-line query?  Or am I going about this the wrong way when I ought to be using a different method?

Comment: you can accept variable as in data type in which they are coming and then convert/cast them inside stroede proc , this will work .

Comment: @Nishad--Thanks.  It turned out that there were two parts to this I needed to fix; one was converting inside the stored proc., and the other was needing to fix the syntax on my variables in the sqlcmd query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nishad had the right idea, but it turns out that something else needed fixing as well.  For the sake of being thorough, here's the final batch file code I wound up using:

```
SET /P Param1 = Enter job number here:
SET /P Param2 = Enter current status here:

sqlcmd -S DevTest -d test_database -Q "EXEC dbo.JStatUpd @jobNum=N'%Param1%', @stat=%Param2%"

PAUSE
```

It was only with this specific formatting that I could actually get my user-entered values to work properly; @echo showed me that I was getting blanks no matter what I entered, so I started playing with the query parameter formats and found that this worked.